# Link object file to a Delphi project that compiled by C++ builder XE5/XE6

Tags: macos, delphi, c++builder, c++builder-xe6

I ve a C++ library. I build a static library with C++ builder XE6 for Win32, Win64 and OSX.

I link this static library from my delphi project.

```
{$if defined(WIN32)}
  {$L obj\testlib_win32.obj}
{$elseif defined(WIN64)}
  {$L obj\testlib_win64.o}
{$elseif defined(MACOS)}
  {$L obj\testlib_osx.a}
{$endif}
```

Compiling for Win32 and Win64 platforms are success.
But when i try to compile the project with OSX, i got an compile error

```
[dccosx Error] test.pas (100): E2045 Bad object file format: 'test_osx.a'
```

C++ Builder creates ELF32 format object files. Can not delphi link ELF32 object format?

Comment: Shared library is the obvious way out of this bind

Comment: dccosx does support `.a` files in ELF format. Are you SURE the `.a` file is actually using ELF?

Comment: I build .a files with C++ Builder XE6. I ve checked the format with objconv.exe. It says .a files are in ELF32 format.

Comment: I ve made an example static library project with C++ builder, and an example project with Delphi XE6. this is the download link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4_n_AY0yqNrdlhkUkJRMllIbk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the link by @ErayHanoglu is broken now btw